# Recharts: How can I add arrow head to a line in scatter to indicate direction

Tags: reactjs, charts, recharts

I'm using Recharts and I have a composed chart with Scatter inside. I'm using the line prop to connect the scatters, but I would like the lines to indicate the direction of the line like the lines were arrows or something like that. How can I do it? Here is my scatter:

`<Scatter name="Name" dataKey="lorem" fill={#000} legendType="diamond" shape="diamond" onAnimationEnd={onLoad} line={line && { stroke: '#cecece', strokeWidth: 0.5 }} />`
[The scatter with lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqAaG.png)

I tried to use all line props that I found like lineType. I also know that I can pass a custom line. But this component receives just the coordinates of my scatters.